# Ref Cursor with sysdate in where clause that use in LOOPING

Tags: oracle, procedure

I want to insert looping with procedure, but when it's execute the error message is "ORA-01555: snapshot too old: rollback segment number  with name "" too small". Is that a problem to do looping with sysdate in ref cursor clause?

here is my procedure

````
PROCEDURE AUTO_REGISTER_EXPIRED_POLICY
    (
        P_STATUS                    OUT VARCHAR2
        ,P_ERROR_MESSAGE            OUT VARCHAR2
    )
    IS
    P_USER_ID varchar2(3);
        
    CURSOR C_GET_DTL_POLIS IS

    SELECT pm.OFFICE, pm.SUBCLASS, pm.RESV, pm.YEAR, pm.MONTH, pm.SEQUENCE, pm.END_NO

    FROM  POLICY_MAIN pm
    
    where to_char(trunc(exp_date), 'yyyymm') = to_char(add_months(trunc(sysdate)+0, 3),'yyyymm')
    and not exists
    ;
    BEGIN
    p_user_id := 'adm';
    
    FOR REC IN C_GET_DTL_POLIS

        LOOP
        PACKAGE_POLICY_RENEWAL_REVIEW.INSERT_RENEW
        (
            rec.office,
            rec.subclass,
            rec.resv,
            rec.year,
            rec.month,
            rec.sequence, 
            rec.end_no
            p_status,
            p_error_message
        );
        
        END LOOP;
        
    insert into log_renewal_review
    select office, subclass, resv, year, month, sequence, end_no,
    'LAPSED BY SYSTEM' REMARKS, 
    sysdate from renewal_review
    where to_char(exp_date, 'yyyymm') = to_char(add_months(trunc(sysdate)+0, 3),'yyyymm')
    and review_sts = '1'
    ;
           

    P_STATUS        := '1';
    P_ERROR_MESSAGE := 'OK';
    

    EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN

    P_STATUS    := '0';
    P_ERROR_MESSAGE := SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 1, 100)
    ROLLBACK;
    END AUTO_REGISTER_EXPIRED_POLICY;```

when I look for solution mostly said id because sysdate is change time by time and it changed every time it insert data one by one.

Please Help me to find what is the problem? is it ok to use sysdate in ref cursor for looping?
````

Comment: This is not a valid source code. The query for cursor `C_GET_DTL_POLIS` is cut in the middle (there is nothing after `and not exists` condition) and therefore invalid. Please attach a correct source code. For further investigation you should attach the code for `PACKAGE_POLICY_RENEWAL_REVIEW.INSERT_RENEW` procedure. I am pretty sure that the problem is connected to `PACKAGE_POLICY_RENEWAL_REVIEW.INSERT_RENEW` and some DML's on the `POLICY_MAIN`.

Comment: The ORA-01555 error has nothing to do with your SYSDATE issue (which may be an issue with your *data* but not the cause of the failure). ORA-01555 is happening because your procedure is taking too long to execute against too many other committed transactions in your database. Your UNDO capacity is exhausted and Oracle can no longer maintain a consistent image of what the data looked like to rollback to if needed. Talk to your DBA about possible fixes, but be prepared to work with smaller chunks of data if they can't increase your UNDO space or reduce the number of other transactions.

Comment: Also, if there's a way to avoid looping in your code, look for that. Looping row-by-row takes exponentially longer to run compared to a single set operation, and tends not to be very scalable.

Comment: Do you, by any chance, COMMIT within the PACKAGE_POLICY_RENEWAL_REVIEW.INSERT_RENEW procedure? If so, don't; COMMIT in a loop quite often leads to ORA-01555. Commit only once, outside of the loop.

Comment: @pmdba yeah in the procedure that I call has some commit. Well thankyou, I'll try other way.

Comment: @Littlefoot yeah I use COMMIT in INSERT_RENEW. Well Thankyou.